# solr sort null first, then created_dt desc

Tags: solr

I am trying to sort based on datatime field, in desc order, but with nulls first. I have attempted to use &sort=nullsFirst, created_dt desc in many variations, but always get Can't determine a Sort Order (asc or desc) in sort spec. Any ideas how I do this?

Comment: do you have sortMissingLast=true for your sorting field in your schema.xml?

Comment: All you have to do is add the sortMissingLast=true to your fieldType and restart solr.
<fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true" sortMissingLast="true"/>. You will find date field to have the nulls at the bottom.

Comment: You probably want `sortMissingFirst` and not `sortMissingLast` to get those without a value first :-) I'm not sure if `sortMissingFirst` and `sortMissingLast` are supported for point fields, but that would be quick to verify.

Comment: Oh, so, if I want the user to be able to choose asc / desc sorting, I will have to index all fields twice, to be able to choose nulls first or last? Is this not possible query time?

Comment: I dont think so it is possible with query without re-indexing the data.

Comment: If you want to do it on a per request basis, add a second boolean field with true/false. You can then use this field to place the documents with no value where you want, `has_value desc, value asc` will show those with a value first, then the other documents. `has_value asc, value asc` will show those without value first. Since it's boolean field, it shouldn't grow the index size very much (just make sutre to include it with your documents when indexing or create a yodate request processor that adds the field). The field only has to be indexed, not stored.,